# Proof that $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x<y\}$ is an open set.

Tags: general-topology

To demonstrate that $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:  x<y\}$ is an open set.

I begin with something like that:

If $(x,y)\in S$ then there exists $B_{y-x}((x,y))=\{P\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|P-(x,y)\|<y-x\}$. So if $(s,t)\in B_{y-x}((x,y))$ so that:

(1) $s-x\leq|s-x|\leq\|(s,t)-(x,y)\|<y-x$

and

(2) $y-t\leq|t-y|\leq\|(s,t)-(x,y)\|<y-x$

And we have: $s<y$ and $-t<-x$, therefore $s-t<y-x$. But I want to obtain that $s<t$ to prove that $(s,t)\in S$.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Note if $(a,b) \in B_e(x,y)$ then $x-e < a < x+e$ and $y-e < b < y+e$ (but not vice versa)

Comment: Do you mind using that $f(x,y) = x - y$ is continuous? $S = f^{-1}(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: If $a=y-x$ then a ball of radius a/4 with the center in (x,y) is completely inside S.

Comment: Have you drawn some pictures? If you do, you'll see that $B_{y-x}((x,y))$ is not contained in $S$. The picture may suggest an appropriate radius to try.

Comment: This won't work.  If you take $(x+\frac 12(y-x), y-\frac 12(y-x))$ such will be in the Ball as $|(x,y),(x+d, y-d)|=\sqrt 2 d$ and $\sqrt 2\frac 12(y-x) < y-x$.   You need a slight shift on the radius.  Try: take a point $(w,u)$ so that $w < u$.  Now what is the closest point on the line $y=x$ to $(w,u)$? [Hint: it's *not* straight down.]  Take *that* as your radius.

Comment: .... or to play it safe take $(y-x)\times \frac 1{100000}$ as your radius.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)\in S$. Then $y=x+t$, with $t>0$.

Consider an open disc of radius $\frac{t}{\sqrt 2}$ about $(x,y)$. Then, as required, this disc is in $S$.